# psql: Relation does not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql, quoted-identifier

I get the following error:

```
test=# Select * from Venue;
ERROR:  relation "venue" does not exist
LINE 1: Select * from Venue;
```

But as you can see here the table exist:

[image]

I have already spent more than 2 hours, and I cant find my error

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Comment: try your select statment like - Select * from public."Venue"

Comment: Hello everybody thanks for your help,
so the problem was that I had several open connections to vagrant. After I restarted my computer everything worked fine